# Where can I get the latest Clang x64-ARM cross-compiler?

Tags: arm, clang, cross-compiling, arm64

Sorry for such a stupid question, but I guess I'm not alone in this. IMHO, this topic may be of interest to many SO users.

I couldn't find a Clang x64-ARM cross-compiler binaries online.

The official LLVM/Clang documentation says that the compilers can be downloaded from the [llvm-project](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/tags) repo, and this is true.

However, it only contains precompiled binaries for native platforms.

No cross-compilers.

For example, it is not possible to load the Clang compiler to build ARM binaries on x86 Intel Linux.

Comment: @toyotaSupra https://apt.llvm.org/ says `Packages are available for amd64, i386 (except for recent Ubuntu), s390x and arm64 (aka aarch64).`. I mean that `arm` architecture is absent. Anyway, thanks for this information! BTW, I'm not sure that this is about cross-compilers.

Comment: You don't need a separate Clang binary to cross-compile, any version of it can compile for any platform. You just need the standard library for the target platform.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Clang could be prebuilt with several platforms or simply with host one. I've tried to install Clang from apt but it cannot compile ARM or AARCH64.

Comment: Technically maybe a distribution could disable some targets, but I don't think anybody does that. What's your distribution? Ubuntu Clang can do that, assuming you have the right standard library installed, and pass the right flags. Just tried it, and `clang++ blah.cpp --target=aarch64-linux-gnu -c` works (assuming I don't include any standard headers, and don't try to link).

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I was wrong. I forgot about `--target=armv7-linux-gnu`. Thanks a lot! It works.

Comment: @toyota or HolyBlackCatSupra Would you please leave an answer to this question?

Comment: @toyotaSupra I just don't want to offend you with this, because you wrote the key information in the comments. Let me know if you want me to add an answer.

Comment: I don't want to write an answer, since this is a simple issue, and I bet it was already discussed here before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For comprehensive information on installing the LLVM/Clang cross-compiler, refer to the official website:

- https://apt.llvm.org

For example, to install Clang-18:

```
wget https://apt.llvm.org/llvm.sh
chmod +x llvm.sh
sudo ./llvm.sh -18
```

The installed Clang will include backends for various architectures like `armv7` or `aarch64`.

You can activate a specific backend using the `--target=` argument.

To use `clang-18` as a cross-compiler for `armv7`, execute the following command:

```
clang-18 --target=armv7-linux-gnu -c main.c
```